# sorting numbers on Babbage's analytic engine

Tags: history

I read that Babbage analytic engine is Turing complete. I wonder, how could I sort array of numbers on it? Imagine that I have numbers in storage and I want to sort them. How can I do that? The biggest problem is, in my opinion, the fact that analytic engine does not have a card which fetches a number into ingress column from a column in storage where column's number is taken from the other ingress column.

Comment: Did you try looking for a proof of Turing-completeness? That should address the issues you raise. (If you do find a proof, please write an answer to your question!)